# PHP Database connection without ODBC

Tags: php, database, odbc, ole

I'm searching for a solution to connect to a Database (no matter the provider), with PHP.
BUT, I don't want to use the ODBC drivers.

I found that OLE DB is an alternative, but what are the possibilities if I want to use nix?

Comment: PHP's native PDO? http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: That was in my mind, but I wasn't confident If it is using odbcs or not

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting